# UBUNTU INITIALIZATION PROBLEM

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia

I'm having trouble booting Ubuntu, I use dual boot with Windows 10 and when I try to get into Ubuntu I get the following message on a black screen:

```
 /dev/nuvme0n1p6: clean, 304834/7749632 files, 4888602/30984960 blocks
```

I tried some solutions on the internet how to press:

> Ctrl + Alt + F2

and type:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

and then:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

because someone with this same error reported to be a problem with Nvidia.

I would like to know if anyone has had the same error and how it solved, I am very concerned because many college folders are there.

---

I followed the steps, but they did not solve my problem. follow the link with the photos taken during the execution: [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQURD.jpg)

Comment: If you have a bootable USB with ubuntu on it, now would be a good time to "try ubuntu" and boot from that USB - you can then save your college folders to another USB in case this problem gets worse

Comment: I'd also encourage you to `sudo apt purge ~nnvidia` and then reboot.  Don't reinstall the drivers immediately.

Comment: That message is not an error.

Comment: @OrganicMarble in my case it is an error because linux does not start

Comment: Nope, it is unrelated to your issue.

Comment: @OrganicMarble none of the suggested solutions solved my problem. I had to reinstall Linux.

Answer (score 0):

if it is from NVIDIA follow this:

1. Reboot
2. In grub select Ubuntu and click 'E'
3. Where is 'quiet splash' write to 'quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0'
4. Click F10 to save and boot.

If this worked you must make this changes permanent by doing:

1. Open terminal
2. do `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
3. Add the same params in line with "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT"
4. Exit nano doing Ctrl+X + Y + Enter (your keybinds can be different)
5. do `sudo update-grub`

This must work if is nvidia problem.

Comment: I followed the steps, but they did not solve my problem.

follow the link with the photos taken during the execution: [link](https://imgur.com/a/Pc56m7X)